# Prevent a race condition for Signal handling in Python3

Tags: python, race-condition

I am developing a Python app on Debian that requires some cleanup functions while it shuts down from ether normal operation, or from a catchable signal call. Here is some psudocode:

```
def exitHandler(sign, frame)
    ...
    variousCleanUp commands
    ...
    program ends here

def main()
    signal.signal(SIGINT, exitHandler)
    signal.signal(SIGTERM, exitHandler)
```

Problem with this is that I have detected that when closing the program, causes both SIGINT and SIGTERM to be sent. And as such the exitHandler function is called twice, which shouldb't happen.

What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag

```
execution = False

def exitHandler(sign, frame):
    global execution
    if execution:
        return
    execution = True
    ... # Rest of the code here
```

if you have real concurrency, use `threading.Lock`

```
...
lock_obj = threading.Lock()
...

def exitHandler(sign, frame):
    with lock_obj:
        ...
```